# How to find a post using XML-RPC without knowing ID

Tags: custom-field, get-posts, xml-rpc

I'm using the following function to retrieve individual posts from an external server using the WordPress XML-RPC Post API:

```
    public function get_post() {

        include("lib/xmlrpc.inc");
        $function_name = "wp.getPost";

        $url = "http://local.wordpress.dev/xmlrpc.php";

        $client = new xmlrpc_client($url);
        $client->return_type = 'phpvals';

        $message = new xmlrpcmsg(
                $function_name, 
                array(
                    new xmlrpcval(0, "int"), //blog_id
                    new xmlrpcval("admin", "string"), //username
                    new xmlrpcval("password", "string"), //password
                    new xmlrpcval("318", "string") //post_id
                    )
                );

        $resp = $client->send($message);

        var_dump($resp);

    }
```

If I don't know the post_id of the post I'm wanting to retrieve but I do know a custom meta key value, can I still retrieve the post?

For example, let's say I had a `meta_key` of `misc_id` wit ha value of `26`. Could I use the XML-RPC WordPress Post API to find a post that matched that or would I have to use MySQL in order to accomplish this?